# Obtener un String de un String[]

Tags: android

Tengo un array de string

```
  private String[] personas= { "Lucas Lemos", "Fabricio Quiroga", "Maurano Pepe" , "Juan del Toro" };
```

el cual muestro en una lista, Quiero que cada vez que el usuario seleccione el nombre de la persona se muestre su informacion personal ( la cual tengo en otros Strings[]
 ¿Como obtengo el ID del String seleccionado dentro del array?

Comment: Nicolas que control deseas usar, un spinner?

Answer (score 2):

#### El titulo de tu pregunta es "Obtener un String de un String[]",

Se pueden obtener el valor del elemento dentro del array de Strings mediante el indice.

Por ejemplo si deseamos obtener el primer valor, recuerda que en un [Array](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html) el primer elemento tiene el indice 0:

```
String primer_elemento = personas[0]:
```

`primer_elemento` tendría el valor de "Lucas Lemos".

Algunos controles cuentan con un adapter el cual pueden ser llenado con los datos de un array de strings, para obtener el valor cuando seleccionas un elemento regularmente se cuenta con un metodo el que recibe el parametro `position` el cual puede ser usado como indice para obtener los valores dentro del arreglo.

Por otra parte, si deseas iterar sobre todos los Por elementos y obtener su valor puedes realizar esto:

```
String[] personas = { "Lucas Lemos", "Fabricio Quiroga", "Maurano Pepe" , "Juan del Toro" };
for (String s: personas) {           
        System.out.println("nombre : "  + s); 
    }
```

y tendrías una salida:

```
nombre : Lucas Lemos
nombre : Fabricio Quiroga
nombre : Maurano Pepe
nombre : Juan del Toro
```

#### También preguntas: ¿Como obtengo el ID del String seleccionado dentro del array?

Me parece que te refieres al indice, puedes realizarlo de esta forma, ejemplo:

```
int indice = Arrays.asList(personas).indexOf("Juan del Toro");
```

Donde tendrías como resultado `3` que sería el indice del elemento en el arreglo.

Answer (score 1):

Si entendi bien, lo que quieres se logra con esto:

```
int index = Arrays.asList(personas).indexOf("Maurano Pepe");
```